# why is $f_X(x) = 1 \cdot \mathbb{\chi}_{[0,1]}$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

in Probability and Random Processes by Geoffrey R. Grimmett, David R.

there is this example that is driving me crazy :

[image]

I just can't get my head around why is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ even a joint distribution function as $\int_{[0,1]^2} x^{-1} d \lambda$ doesn't even converge in the first place.

I'm fairly sure that's a typo, right ?

Comment: The joint density is $x^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant y\leqslant x\leqslant 1}=x^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2}\mathbf{1}_{y\leqslant x}$. You're missing the last factor in your expression.

Comment: Your integral should be $\int_0^1 \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x} dx dy$ which does converge

Comment: Perfect. thanks !